# What is the preferred way to read and write to a .properties file from within a Tapestry application

Tags: java, glassfish, tapestry, read-write, properties-file

What is the preferred way to read and write to a `.properties` file from within a Tapestry application?

I have a Tapestry web application and at some point, I need to read (and write only once) some properties from a `.properties` file.

The application is deployed on a Glassfish server (3.1.2.2).

Where is the best location to write such a file and is there a preferred way on how to do it? It would be nice if it would be packed somewhere where the admins could access it without much troubles?

Ty in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to query and edit your own application configuration options?  Have you thought about persisting it into a data base and discarded the idea for some particular reason?  Maybe it would be a more consistent idea

Comment: I have thought of that, however, due to some requests and limitations, it's not an option. Nevertheless, a good suggestion, deserves an upvote :)

Comment: In that case, you should talk to your operator in order to secure a well known directory in the production machine where to store your .properties, outside the deployment path.  I do not know a single thing about Tapestry framework :(  ; in your case I would write some kind of Singleton, synchronized properties wrapper class and just dump it to the file at every change... I am sorry I can be of no more help

Comment: Nevertheless, the advice you gave is sound :)

Answer (score 1):

We use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) and it works really well for us. It is very easy to configure as a service/Injectable Object and you can always use BeanEditForm for editing such a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Although this approach is best suited for localization, you can use `messages` for your problem.
First, create new `.properties` file in the same folder where your pages (`.tml`) are, or add them as a `resource bundle`. Also, name the `.properties` file same as the page. Then, you can inject the properties in your code like this:

```
@Inject
private Messages messages;
```

Then you can use built in methods `.get()` and `.format()` to read and write to properties.
Visit these to links to find more information about this:
http://tapestry.apache.org/localization.html
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/Messages.html